# Getting an error when trying to scrape a table

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get some data from a webpage, but I keep getting error. Tried searching google, but I can not seem to find a good solution.

```
url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/"
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'table'})
print(table)


data = [[td.text.strip() for td in tr.findChildren('td')]
        for tr in table.findChildren('tr')]
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ejer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/stock_analysis.py", line 13, in <module>
    for tr in table.findChildren('tr')]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findChildren'
```

Comment: **`Sorry, we couldn't find your page`**  the webpage shows this of the url you are trying to get. If you print _table_ it will be `None` you don't have the html to parse

Comment: Sorry for that. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put the class of the table has, instead of just table and in your case it has `cmc-table`

```
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'cmc-table'}
```

Try this it gets the table

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that the URL you used is not proper. Please check it once and use the proper one.